# udev rule successfully grabbing device, but failing at creating symlink

Tags: linux, bash, sh, udev, systemctl

I am trying to create a udev rule for a specific device, more specifically a usb snes controller. The device information is as follows:

```
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:0583:2060.0006/hidraw/hidraw0':
    KERNEL=="hidraw0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:0583:2060.0006':
    KERNELS=="0003:0583:2060.0006"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="hid"
    DRIVERS=="hid-generic"
    ATTRS{country}=="21"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-2:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usbhid"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="03"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="01"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2':
    KERNELS=="1-2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="11"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="2"
    ATTRS{devspec}=="          (null)"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="2060"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0583"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB,2-axis 8-button gamepad  "
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{speed}=="1.5"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="43"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0417"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{devspec}=="          (null)"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.17.14-arch1-1-ARCH xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="12"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="9254"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x9d2f"
    ATTRS{devspec}==""
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="122"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="f"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x21"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x380c"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x17aa"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

I wrote a udev rule `99-snes-controller.rules` to match that device and create a symlink to a more stable name.

```
KERNEL=="hidraw[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0583", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2060", SYMLINK+="snes-controller"
```

Now, testing the device and rules actually grab's the correct rule for the device, but fails to actually create the symlink. Testing with gives me the output

```
LINK 'snes-controller' /etc/udev/rules.d/99-snes.rules:1
handling device node '/dev/hidraw0', devnum=c239:0, mode=0600, uid=0, gid=0
preserve permissions /dev/hidraw0, 020600, uid=0, gid=0
preserve already existing symlink '/dev/char/239:0' to '../hidraw0'
found 'c239:0' claiming '/run/udev/links/\x2fsnes-controller'
creating link '/dev/snes-controller' to '/dev/hidraw0'
preserve already existing symlink '/dev/snes-controller' to 'hidraw0'
```

However, there is not a symlink called "snes-controller" in /dev/. Just `hidrawX`

Any ideas?